# How to prevent full re-rendering of view on an ajax request

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a master layout page containing Primefaces(6.1) p:layout. With every ajax request made from this view, I found that all the pages in the view(nested pages inside the master layout) are being re-rendered again. The idea is to render only the current form components or at least contents in the current layout (center,west,north) with ajax calls. Components are updated using RequestContext so for events i never add update attribute at all.

Is this an expected behavior with p:ajax or am i missing something ?  Also how to make sure that PPR is actually working ?

UPDATED page layout (nested pages also follow the same structure. have never used a template)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
 <title>HOME</title>
 <style>
#westPanel {
 z-index: 2 !important;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}

#westPanel div {
 overflow: visible;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}
</style>

</h:head>

<h:body>

 <h:outputStylesheet name="css/commonStyle.css" />


 <p:layout styleClass="ui-layout-pane-blank" fullPage="true"
  stateful="false" >

  <p:layoutUnit id="northPanel" position="north" size="40" gutter="0"
   resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">
   
    <ui:include src="/store/AMC/header.xhtml"></ui:include>
   
  </p:layoutUnit>

  <p:layoutUnit id="westPanel" position="west" size="300" header="Menu"
   gutter="0" resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true">
   <ui:include src="/store/AMC/menu.xhtml"></ui:include>
  </p:layoutUnit>

  <p:layoutUnit id="centerPanel" gutter="0" position="center">
   <h:form id="centralForm">
    <ui:include src="#{centralLayoutMB.centralLayout}.xhtml" />
   </h:form>
  </p:layoutUnit>

 </p:layout>


 <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
  onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide();" />

 <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" draggable="false" closable="false"
  resizable="false" showHeader="false">
  <p:graphicImage url="/resources/images/icons/load.gif" />

 </p:dialog>

</h:body>


</html>
```

**THE DEBUG CONSOLE OUTPUT**

2017-11-22 10:15:01 INFO  stdout:71 - START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1

```
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/masterLayout.xhtml @7,9 <h:head> Component[-2048881072_7a1f71a3] Created: javax.faces.component.UIOutput
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/masterLayout.xhtml @25,9 <h:body> Component[-2048881072_7a1f7189] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/masterLayout.xhtml @27,51 <h:outputStylesheet> Component[-2048881072_7a1f71ef] Created: javax.faces.component.UIOutput
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/masterLayout.xhtml @31,48 <p:layout> Component[-2048881072_7a1f71e2] Created: org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/masterLayout.xhtml @34,59 <p:layoutUnit> Component[-2048881072_7a1f71c8] Created: org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnit
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @7,26 <h:form> Component[-1732486783_6925632b] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @9,67 <p:hotkey> Component[-1732486783_69256305] Created: org.primefaces.component.hotkey.Hotkey
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @11,47 <p:toolbar> Component[-1732486783_69256370] Created: org.primefaces.component.toolbar.Toolbar
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @14,63 <h:panelGrid> Component[-1732486783_69256344] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @16,20 <p:commandLink> Component[-1732486783_692563be] Created: org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLink
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @18,50 <p:graphicImage> Component[-1732486783_69256398] Created: org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImage
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @28,47 <p:commandButton> Component[-1732486783_692563e1] Created: org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @33,49 <p:commandButton> Component[-1732486783_692563ec] Created: org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @38,48 <p:commandButton> Component[-1732486783_692563db] Created: org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @43,42 <p:menuButton> Component[-1732486783_692563c6] Created: org.primefaces.component.menubutton.MenuButton
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @47,45 <p:menuitem> Component[-1732486783_69256220] Created: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @51,51 <p:menuitem> Component[-1732486783_6925622f] Created: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @56,52 <p:menuitem> Component[-1732486783_6925621a] Created: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @60,44 <p:menuitem> Component[-1732486783_69256209] Created: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem
2017-11-22 10:15:01 DEBUG component:485 - /store/AMC/header.xhtml @65,49 <p:menuitem> Component[-1732486783_69256274] Created: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem
```

and so on it goes... until it meets the ajax event.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you thought that "Full Restore View" meant. So far, it looks too much like that you confused "render" with "restore" and actually wanted to ask why the entire view is re-rendered as if it were a synchronous request or a render="@all" was used. The "restore view" is namely part of normal JSF lifecycle but usually takes no more than a few microseconds.

Comment: @BalusC yeah you are right, i may have confused with the terms.  with the ajax requests made, i see on the debug console that all the pages contained within master layout are restored which takes up some seconds in the process. I dont want to restore the header or west parts when i am at the center

Comment: Partial processing is not relevant to rendering. As BalusC mentioned, you probably have `update="@all"` or a non-AJAX POST or one of PF's autoupdating components wrapping everything. It's impossible to say what exactly without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your question is really just " Is this an expected behavior with AJAX or am i missing something ?" then no, this isn't some inherent behavior of AJAX, and yes, you are missing something.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov I use RequestContext to update and it works well. Although the re-render starts the very moment i make an ajax request which loads(takes about 4-8 seconds) all the pages in the masterlayout page( p:layout) on the console while the actual view remains intact which seems like normal ajax. so is it the p:layout causing the issue? I am not using any templates btw

Comment: Is this console output what the question is about? Then there were no re-rendering and you're actually talking about restoring view?

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov Well, that's what i thought initially but i was corrected by BalusC. I don't know what to make of the console output. the ajax is not fast enough and I'm not sure if PPR is working in this case.